# Detect click in the javascript without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do this in simple javascript without using JQuery?

I would like a simple way for execute this.

```
    $('body').on('click','a[name=bt_del_dependent]',function(){
        console.log('id:'+ this.id);  
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: That's easy, you add `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` and write it exactly like that ?

Comment: you mean in plain javascript, without using jquery? Because jquery **IS** just some helper stuff for javascript to begin with.

Comment: Exactly! The JQuery is "very heavy" for meet several situations. I would like a simple way for execute the my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegated event handlers would look something like this

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    if ( 
         e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a' &&  
         e.target.name === 'bt_del_dependent' 
    ) {

         console.log('id:'+ e.target.id);  

    }

}, false);
```

It's still not exactly the same, you'd have to check for `closest` match to the `event.target`, not just the `event.target`, and that would require writing a `closest` method as well

Comment: That's it! I changed "console.log('id:'+ event.target.id);" per "console.log('id:'+ e.target.id);" and it worked! Thanks! =)